# How to force a login using YII?

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I have a user that needs to authenticate his account via an OTP. TO authenticate, he fills in his OTP and it verifies the cellphone number. Once authenticated, I want to force him to log in. I.e. So he doesn't still have to manually login. So, for this form, I basically have:

```
if($model->validate())
{
   // Force Login
   $this->redirect(array('/site/index'));    
}
```

Using only one of his credentials (namely his cellphone number), I need to force him to login. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure is explained in the documentation for `CWebUser`:

1. The user provides information needed for authentication.
2. An identity instance is created with the user-provided information.
3. Call IUserIdentity::authenticate to check if the identity is valid.
4. If valid, call `CWebUser::login` to login the user, and Redirect the user browser to `returnUrl`.

You should already have an identity class that implements `IUserIdentity`. Usually this is a class deriving from [`CUserIdentity`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity), which takes a username and a password on construction. There is a great degree of freedom here: you can decide not to derive from `CUserIdentity` and use your own custom identity class that authenticates any way you wish, or you can derive from `CUserIdentity` and override the `authenticate` method to authenticate with the OTP.

The procedure would then be exactly as above:

```
$identity = new MyIdentity(...); // you decide what params it takes
if ($identity->authenticate()) {
    $user = Yii::app()->user;
    $user->login($identity);
    $this->redirect($user->returnUrl);
}
```