# Yii cookie based login

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, yii

How to handle that correctly? http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/topics.auth in the Cookie-based Login section says that that's not good to store important imformation in cookies. And I do think the same. They advise to do the following:

> When a user successfully logs in by filling out a login form, we
>   generate and store a random key in both the cookie state and in
>   persistent storage on server side (e.g. database). Upon a subsequent
>   request, when the user authentication is being done via the cookie
>   information, we compare the two copies of this random key and ensure a
>   match before logging in the user. If the user logs in via the login
>   form again, the key needs to be re-generated.

And I agree. But how to implement that? Where I have to write the code which will check the cookie and restore the session? Any kind of helper or what? Or it must be beforeRender() function of controller? Is there any tutorials? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Authentication can be achieved using either sessions or cookies.

To enable cookie based authentication, set the `allowAutoLogin` property of the user component.

In your *protected/config/main.php*

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'loginUrl'=>'site/login',
        'class' => "UserIdentity",
    ),
```

When authenticating the user credentials. set the cookie validity period, for example :

> Yii::app()->user->login($identity,3600*24*7);   // Remember me for a
>   week

EDIT

You can store additional information using `setSate`

```
$this->setState('myhash', $myhash);
```

This will be stored in either sessions or cookie, depending on your config value. You can use both at the same time.

To force a value into a session, use the global session object.

```
Yii::app()->session['hash'] = $hash;
```

To force a value into cookies

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['hash'] = new CHttpCookie('hash', $hash);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I noticed that is such case all info is stored in the cookie. For example email, is_admin, etc. And users can change that, right? How to hadnle that? I don't want to store all that information. I want to store only some hash.... But where then I have to write the code which checks the hash and fetches the data?

Comment: Thanks! Could you advise me where should I check hash got from cookie and fetch info from the database using that hash? In which method? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. I was responding to your comment "...I want to store only some hash.... But where then I have to write the code which checks the hash and fetches the data?..." I was merely showing you how to store and fetch values from session/cookies.

Comment: In which method?   I think u can get that from CWebUser: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769234/how-to-force-a-login-using-yii    And where to store it: server-side database, as quoted from your link above:
"... these information should be restored on the server side by reading from some persistent storage on the server side (e.g. database)."

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/741/enhance-security-of-cookie-based-login/

I'll add that you must specify in params that you overrided `CWebUser`:

```
'user' => array(
    'class'  => 'WebUser',
    ......
```

And another important thing, that session cookie will not be set if `Yii::app()->user->login()` second param (cookie lifetime) is not specified.